# Flutter firebase realtime database

Tags: database, flutter, firebase

this is my main.dart and it seems like it can be run, but it just showing white page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: RealTimeData(),
    );
  }
}

class RealTimeData extends StatelessWidget {
  RealTimeData({super.key});
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref('UsersData/DyumeB1voaQxEqQVjbccha7v2cs2/readings');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Real time Database"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
              query: ref,
              itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.child('light').value.toString()));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it also does something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKC79.png) if i run it

after i click run again, it will show me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dlOe.png)

at least i could run it and shows the content that i call from the firebase realtime database

Comment: It is in debug mode. To avoid that, From VS Code 'RUN AND DEBUG' tab -> BREAKPOINTS -> Uncheck the two checkboxes (All Exceptions and Uncaught Exceptions)

Comment: Error: Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/gifan/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.10.0/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:255:11
options != null
"FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app."

Comment: You're not passing the necessary configuration option to `initializeApp`. I recommend following the steps in the documentation on [adding Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web).